# Mocked selectors (reselect + jest) stopped working with Jest v.29 (upgraded from v.27)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, jestjs, reselect

I used to have a global file with all my selector mocks. It was a list of all my store selectors and looked like below:

```
jest.mock('redux/mainData/selectors', () => ({
  selectLoading: jest.fn(() => false),
  selectData: jest.fn(() => [{ id: '1' }]),
}));
```

It used to work like a charm, but when I tried upgrading Jest to v29 it doesn't any more.

In `jest.setup.ts` there was (and is):

```
jest.mock('react-redux', () => ({
  useSelector: jest.fn(fn => fn()),
}));
```

When I'm testing a component, that has:

```
const data = useSelector(selectData);
```

and then below in the component

```
data?.map(...)
```

I'm getting:

> Error: Uncaught [TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined
> (reading 'data')]

My file with mocked selectors has about 300 mocked selectors so now basically every test fails.

I tried doing:

```
jest.mock('redux/mainData/selectors', () => ({
  selectData: () => ([{ id: '1' }]),
}));
```

or

```
jest.mock('redux/mainData/selectors', () => ({
  selectData: jest.fn().mockReturnValueOnce([{}]);
}));
```

but both didn't work.

My example selector:

```
export const selectData = createSelector(
  selectMainData,
  ({data}) => data,
);
```

I'm using Jest v29.5.0 and Reselect v4.1.8

Comment: Looks good to me. Can you create a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example, Try debugging by calling `selectData()`, what result do you get?

Comment: I'm getting `undefined` in the component not matter in which way I try to mock the data. I've also tried `    mocked(selectData).mockImplementation(() =>[]);`

Comment: which version of nodejs are you using?

Comment: Node version 18

Comment: @jake-ferguson I see you put a bounty on this 2 days ago so I assume you still have quite a predicament. Does the [latest version](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest/v/29.6.1) still have this issue? As Lin Du suggested; is it possible for you to create a project on github that reproduces this problem?

Comment: Hey, yes the lates 29.6.1 Jest still producing the same issue with mock selectors not working for me.

GH would be a bit hard since this is a big, old project unfortunately that cannot be shared.